# Common callback function

Tags: ros, c++, callback, thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I've a c++ thread that is checking every x seconds if some robots are active. For that, every robot publishes a topic (/robot1/status). So if the robot is publishing, I know that it is alive.

For that reason, my thread subscribes to all these "status" topics. Is it possible to have a common callback for all the topics or I need one function to every one topic?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65977/common-callback-function/) by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that is possible. Also have a look at [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/) if you want your callback to have a custom parameter, to know which topic (/robot) is the source.

---

Edit:

You could use only one topic and let every robot send messages with a unique id to it.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-06-26**:
Thanks. I'll try with std::bind instead of boost::bind.